# Having the Angular Router render URLs pasted into the browser?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router

I have the router configured like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'topic/:id',
    component: TopicComponent,
    resolve: { topic: TopicResolverService }
  },  
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: SummaryCardListComponent
  }
]
```

And if I visit a topic directly like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/topic/concepts%2Fdemand%2Flead-time-demand
```

It redirects to the path `http://localhost:4200/`.

What do we need to do to make the router render the link pasted into the browser?

The topic resolver service looks like this:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TopicResolverService implements Resolve<Topic> {

    constructor( private s: StateService ) { }

    resolve(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        const id = route.paramMap.get('id')
        return this.s.loadingTopicStore$.pipe(
            switchMap(()=>of(this.s.topicStore.findOneByID(id))
        ))
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have for `TopicResolverService `

Comment: It's weird because it should work. Angular's router should handle this correctly.

Comment: I added the TopicResolverService code.

Comment: @Ole Thanks. Do you have anything of relevance in `TopicComponent` that might be causing an issue?

Comment: @KurtHamilton - Thanks - I think it has something to do with the way I constructed the state service.  I'm going to analyze it and I'll post an analysis of it once I figure it out.  Thanks for all the great feedback!

Comment: @KurtHamilton - Thanks again for the guidance.  It helped me figure out the root cause.  I edited the answer with an update of the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use `decodeURIComponent('concepts%2Fdemand%2Flead-time-demand')` on your URI param, which is supposed to be an `:id`, it resolves to `concepts/demand/lead-time-demand`;

Now this baffles angular router, it searches for nested route like:

`http://localhost:4200/topic/concepts/demand/lead-time-demand`

This obviously does not exist, so it falls back to the base URL.

### EDIT FROM QUESTION AUTHOR

I had coded an `Action` that merged `Observable` events, and accidentally included the `Observable` that triggers when the `Topic` store loading was complete.

The action allowed the user to select a Slice of topics (`Concepts`, `Formulas`, `Guides`...) and `on` a select from the user it would navigate to `''` since that's the route that displays the slice.

Anyways since a paste of a URL into the browser that matches the route causes the application to load, this in turn causes the `this.s.loadingTopicStore$` event to fire, and that caused the router to navigate to `''`.

For those interested this was the design of the action:

```
  /**
   * Note that are always only rendering
   * `searchedTopics$` but we also
   * track `selectedTopics$` because
   * we search within this subset when 
   * it's selected.
   * 
   * This also resets `topicStore.query`.
   */
  onSelectTopicCategory() {
    merge(
      this.s.loadingTopicStore$,
      this.s.activeTopicCategory$).
      pipe(untilDestroyed(this)).subscribe(() => {
        this.s.selectedTopics$ = combineLatest(
          this.s.all$,
          this.s.guides$,
          this.s.blogs$,
          this.s.concepts$,
          this.s.formulas$,
          this.s.tasks$,
          this.s.activeTopicCategory$,
          this.s.loadingTopicStore$,
          this.onSelectTopicCategoryFunction)
        this.s.searchedTopics$ = this.s.selectedTopics$
        this.s.topicStore.query = ''

        //We have to subscribe to this otherwise
        //The combine latest function will never fire.
        //The reason is that we are only using
        //searchedTopics in the view, so we 
        //have to fire selectedTopics$ manually.

        this.s.selectedTopics$.
        pipe(untilDestroyed(this)).
        subscribe()
      })
  }
```

And the function that is triggered by the `merge`:

```
  /**
   * Observe the active topic category.  
   * 
   * Note that we navigate to '' when a category
   * is selected such that we can see the selections
   * rendered.
   */
  onSelectTopicCategoryFunction(
    all,
    guides,
    blogs,
    concepts,
    formulas,
    tasks,
    active,
    loading) {
    if (loading == false) {
//      this.router.navigate([''])
      switch (active) {
        case TopicCategories.ALL:
          return all
        case TopicCategories.GUIDES:
          return guides
        case TopicCategories.BLOGS:
          return blogs
        case TopicCategories.CONCEPTS:
          return concepts
        case TopicCategories.FORMULAS:
          return formulas
        case TopicCategories.TASKS:
          return tasks
        default:
          return all
      }
    }
    else return []
  }
```

It's implemented with `@fireflysemantics/slice`:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fireflysemantics/slice

Comment: I constructed the `id` from the path where the markdown document is located, so it is `concepts/demand/lead-time-demand`.  IIUC the problem is hte `/` characters.  Angular does not like that because it's interpreting them as nested paths and it does not have a route for these nested paths?

Comment: So in other words I should not have `/` characters in the `id`?

Comment: Absolutely right, and IMO, if you must have them find a way to double encode them

Comment: This isn't true. As long as you have a URL encoded value you can use it as a route parameter value. https://stackblitz.com/edit/router-template-bflfjc

Comment: Hmmm - Tried changing the `id` to `http://localhost:4200/topic/concepts--demand--lead-time-demand` ... but it still directs back to `localhost:4200`

Comment: @Ole correct. You are allowed slashes in your params, that's not the issue.

Comment: `this.s.topicStore.findOneByID(id)` is this returning what is expected ?